Refer EKS secret or Configmap value in init container
I want to read EKS secret and config-map values in init container , how to do so and is it possible?
Currently we fail a container if a secret or cm value is missing via java code like below
public class StartupHealthProbe implements HealthIndicator {

private static final List<String> MANDATORY_ENV_VARIABLES = List.of(
        "A",
        "B",
        "C",
        "D"
);

private final Environment environment;

public StartupHealthProbe(Environment environment) {
    this.environment = environment;
}

@Override
public Health health() {
    if (!isMandatoryEnvVariablesSet()) {
        return Health.down().build();
    }
    return Health.up().build();
}

boolean isMandatoryEnvVariablesSet() {
    final List<String> missingEnvVariables =
            MANDATORY_ENV_VARIABLES.stream()
                    .filter(envVar -> !environment.containsProperty(envVar))
                    .collect(Collectors.toList());
    if (!missingEnvVariables.isEmpty()) {
        log.error(
                "[CONFIGURATION ERROR] Missing mandatory environment variables: {}", missingEnvVariables);
        return false;
    }
    return missingEnvVariables.isEmpty();
}

}
Is the same functionality achievable using init container , note some of my values come from EKS secret ans some come via configmaps

In your Kubernetes YAML manifest, are you setting env: variables for these settings?  They work the same way for init containers and normal containers.

You can access both secrets and ConfigMaps in init containers the same way you would with regular containers:
initContainers:
  - name: ...
    image: ...
    restartPolicy: Always 
    volumeMounts:
    - name: config-map
      mountPath: /usr/share/file.yml
      subPath: file.yml
    env:
    - name: PASSWORD
      valueFrom:
        secretKeyRef:
          name: secret
          key: password

Above show how to access ConfigMap by mounting it as a volume & how to access a secret as an env variable.
